# Trying to connect c++ client to python server

Tags: python, c++, sockets, boost, websocket

Hi I am trying to get my C++ client to send a message to my python server. My C++ client connects to the server but doesn't send the message and exits the connection. My question is what am I doing wrong, I followed the boost::asio guides and they end up either confirming that my code should work or it is old documentation that still uses io_service instead of io_context. I then tried to do a fresh client start over with the example on https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/sync/websocket_client_sync.cpp 
but I still get the same result.

python server:

```
import socket
import sys


# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#clients = [] #clients connected to
#clients_lock = threading.Lock()
# Bind the socket to the port
server_name = sys.argv[1]
server_address = (server_name, 10000)
print('starting up on %s port %s' % server_address, file = sys.stderr) 
sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(5)



while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print('waiting for a connection', file = sys.stderr) 
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()

    try:
        print('client connected:', client_address, file = sys.stderr) 
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(1024)
            if data.decode() == 'exit':
                print(f"The client said: {data.decode()}")
                reply = f"You told me: {data.decode()}"
                connection.sendall(reply.encode('utf-8'))
            else:
                break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(f"Gracefully shutting down the server!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Well I did not anticipate this: {e}")
```

c++ client:

```
namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;       // from <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

bool ClientToSocket::Connect()
{
try
    {
        // Check command line arguments.
        std::string text = "hi";
        std::string host = "localhost";
        char const* port = "10000";

        // The io_context is required for all I/O
        net::io_context ioc;

        // These objects perform our I/O
        tcp::resolver resolver{ ioc };
        websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws{ ioc };

        // Look up the domain name
        auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        auto ep = net::connect(ws.next_layer(), results);

        // Update the host_ string. This will provide the value of the
        // Host HTTP header during the WebSocket handshake.
        // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
        host += ':' + std::to_string(ep.port());

        // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
        ws.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](websocket::request_type& req)
            {
                req.set(http::field::user_agent,
                    std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                    " websocket-client-coro");
            }));

        // Perform the websocket handshake
        ws.handshake(host, "/");

        // Send the message
        ws.write(net::buffer(std::string(text)));

        // This buffer will hold the incoming message
        beast::flat_buffer buffer;

        // Read a message into our buffer
        ws.read(buffer);

        // Close the WebSocket connection
        ws.close(websocket::close_code::normal);

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully

        // The make_printable() function helps print a ConstBufferSequence
        std::cout << beast::make_printable(buffer.data()) << std::endl;
    }
    catch (boost::system::system_error& error) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << error.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
End Result:
I need the client to send a message to the server and then another client to read the same message and to some calculations with it.
```

Comment: Unfamiliar with the specific tech, but "sockets" and "websockets" are two different things. You want a *socket* client on the C++ side, not a *websocket* one. Websockets work with an established HTTP connection.

Comment: I have tried it with a regular socket as well. With a regular socket it crashes before the connection is made with the web-socket at least I can make the connection but wont send message

Comment: It's frustrating when programs crash, but all crashes happen for a reason. There is no magic. Can you trace the socket code with a debugger?